# Which of two Verilog lines is preferred?

Tags: verilog

If we want a modulus 10 counter (counts from 0 to 9), we can write this:

```
reg [3:0] cnt = 0;
always @(posedge clk) cnt <= (cnt==9) ? 0 : cnt+1;
```

optimization is available if we realize that we don't actually need to compare all the 4 bits of the counter to 9. The code below uses only bit 0 and bit 3 in the comparison.

```
always @(posedge clk) cnt <= ((cnt & 9)==9) ? 0 : cnt+1;
```

Why is the second line of code preferred? Why is it not neccessery to define `reg [3:0] cnt = 0` ?

Comment: If you really want to be explicit about the manual optimization, why not just write `cnt[3] & cnt[0] ? ...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the second line of code preferred?

It's not. It's harder to read, more error-prone for the programmer and has no advantages whatsoever, because conversion of statements like `cnt==9` into logic implementation is what a synthesizer is for.

I.e., unless something goes catastrophically wrong, the first variant is functionally and hardware-wise identical, but much much easier to read.

> optimization is available if we realize that we don't actually need to compare all the 4 bits of the counter to 9.

Ah you probably mean that your counter can theoretically take values 0 to 15, but due to the implemented logic will only take values 0-9.

So, well, a) modern synthesizers recognize that, so that optimization happens automatically, and b) this fact is only useful if you target platform gains anything from this knowledge - but an FPGA has LUTs with which it would do this, and I don't see how that optimization would actually *reduce* anything; you'd always need the same number of LUTs to compare a 4 bit number to 9, far as I can tell.

In case of an FPGA target:

- If you have 4-bit LUTs (or anything larger, as for example the 6-bit LUTs in modern Xilinx FPGAs), you need exactly 1 LUT to do this comparison, no matter how you program it in HDL
- If you have slices with 3-bit LUTs, you need exactly 2
- I'm not aware of any FPGA architecture with 2-LUTs, as that just screams "bad routing vs LUT complexity tradeoff"

In case of a standard cell / ASIC target:

- again, hopefully your synthesizer recognizes `cnt` never exceeds 9, but even if it didn't `(cnt&9)==9` has to compare a 4-bit number to a 4-bit number for `==`, so there's nothing to be won here, as far as I can tell.

Comment: If there is a concern about the other values, the logic could be (cnt>=9) instead of (cnt==9).

Comment: yep, and both would use the same area in an FPGA, probably, unless there's slices with unused full adders, in which case `>=` is probably more efficient than `==` and significantly better than `&9 ==`.

Comment: +1 for this: *"you need exactly 1 LUT to do this comparison, no matter how you program it in HDL"*

Comment: @DaveTweed I should probably add that since this is clocked register assignment, there's also no chance that any succeeding logic be "integrated" into that. Optimizing this has absolutely no point, and I'm a bit confused who told Zohar that this strange `&` based optimization helps

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the synthesizer might recognize that `cnt&9` has only 2 bits that aren't always 0, and therefore be able to optimize the equality check down to a 2-bit operation. Of course that still only matters in the unlikely scenario where you have 2-bit LUTs.